# Show custom link only to certain user groups in magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.8

i'm using a custom template and has a static block using it as a custom menu along with the categories.

I've created a menu using tags

```
    <li>info for non-wholesale users</li>
```

and would like to hide one such tag from wholesale group. how should i proceed?

i'm using magento 1.8.1

Answer (score 2):

The resolution

```
 if(Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()){
          // Get group Id
          $groupId = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerGroupId();
          //Get customer Group name
          $group = Mage::getModel('customer/group')->load($groupId);
        //  echo $group->getCode();
    if($group->getCode()!="retailer"){
    // here  put your code 
    }
    }else{
        // here  put your code 


    }
```

Comment: can i add this code in the static blocks under the CMS pages? or will this be in the template .phtml files?

Comment: you cant add directly this code to static block  if you want to use it in static block than you have to first create a phtml file and than call that file in static block

Comment: Okay. thanks. let me go through the codes and get back to you guys.